# Give an alternative proof of Wilson's theorem ($g$ is a primitive root modulo an odd prime $p$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $(p-1)! = g^{\sum _{k=0}^{p-1} k}$, where $g$ is a primitive root modulo an odd prime $p$, the use it to give an alternative proof of Wilson's theorem.

I was thinking that ${\sum _{k=0}^{p-1} k}$ is of the form $\phi(p-1)(p-1)/2$   right?? and then since $g$ is a primitive root $g^{p}=1$

Answer (score 9):

First of all $g$ is primitive root this means that:
$$\Bbb Z_p^*=\{g^0,g^1,g^2,\cdots,g^{p-2}\}=\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$$
hence the product of the elements of the two sets are equals:
$$(p-1)!\equiv 1\cdot 2\cdots (p-1)\equiv g^0\cdot g^1\cdots g^{p-1}\equiv g^{0+1+2+\cdots+p-1}\equiv g^{{\sum _{k=0}^{p-1} k}}$$
(note that adding $g^{p-1}=1$ does not change the product) and as you noticed we have:
$${\sum _{k=0}^{p-1} k}=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$$ and because $g^p\equiv g$ we have $$(p-1)!\equiv g^{{\sum _{k=0}^{p-1} k}}\equiv g^{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}}\equiv (g^p)^{\frac{(p-1)}{2}}\equiv g^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}$$

but from here we can conclude that $$(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p$$ because if $g$ is a primitive root then $ g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \mod p$

---

**Edit** how to prove that $x\equiv g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \mod p$ ? we know that $g^{p-1}\equiv x^2\equiv 1\mod p$ hence $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv x^2-1\equiv 0 \mod p$ so $x\equiv \mp 1\mod p$

but $x \not \equiv 1\mod p$ because the order of $g$ would be less then $p-1$ which is not psooible, so $x\equiv -1\mod p$

Comment: I don't really get why we have $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv (p-1)!\pmod{p}$. Can you please explain it further?

Comment: I wasn't talking about that. I was asking how did we get the factorial $(p-1)!$ into the congruence in the line where you started from $g^{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k}$? Is it some property of primitive roots modulo odd primes?

Comment: Thanks! Now, it's clear and understandable to me. Upvoted! :)

Comment: After the edit, note that $\{g^0,g^1,\ldots,g^{p-1}\}$ has $p$ elements but the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,p-1\}$ has only $p-1$ elements. I'm not sure but I think you should have the same number of elements in both sets, shouldn't you?

Comment: no they have both $p-1$ elements the repeated element is $1=g^0=g^{p-1}$ does not change anything

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for letting me know. :)